# How to setup Webstorm IDE config for webdriverIO?

Tags: jasmine, mocha.js, webstorm, webdriver-io

Here is how I setup the config in Webstorm, but it is not working.

[Edit configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieFVT.png)

And here is the error which just shows that it is executing the conf file, but actually it doesn't go any further and I have to forcefully terminate it.

[execution is stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIf1v.png)

Comment: https://alippai.github.io/ here is a brief guide

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm doesn't provide any special support for `wdio` test runner and `wdio-mocha-framework`/`wdio-jasmine-framework` frameworks. But you can still run/debug the tests using Node.js run configuration like the follows:

[image]

Comment: Hi I have the same set of config but it is not working. I downloaded a boilerplate project for webdriver io with Jasmine BDD framework: https://github.com/amiya-pattnaik/webdriverIO-with-jasmineBDD

Comment: what do you mean saying that it's not working? does `npm run test` (from readme instructions) work for you?

Comment: I have updated the execution snapshot. It just gets stuck at one point and doesn't move forward.

Comment: does `npm run test` (from readme instructions) work for you?

Comment: Yes, npm run test works for me perfectly when i run it from terminal

Comment: just noticed... what about specifying a correct path to config file in your run configuration? working dir is your project root dir, config file is located in `<project dir>/test/config/` folder, but you are passing non-existing `wdio.config.js` instead of your actual config (`./test/config/suite.jasmine.conf.js`) to *wdio*... Do you have any special reason for doing this?

Comment: I have updated my current webstorm config in the description under my question. Please have a look at that. Thanks for looking out at my issue

Comment: in your both links, you are still using `wdio.config.js` located in the project root dir. But there is no such file in https://github.com/amiya-pattnaik/webdriverIO-with-jasmineBDD, and `npm test` there runs `node node_modules/webdriverio/bin/wdio ./test/config/suite.jasmine.conf.js`. Please share your actual project so that I can see what's wrong

Comment: Hi Lena... Please use this github link for the project. It is a very basic webdriverio-test project: https://github.com/bhullaris/webdriverio-test

Comment: thanks, I was able to recreate the issue on windows - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31745 - but it looks windows-specific, and you are using OSX... Will check on mac oX later, when I'm back in the office

Comment: Thanks. Please let me know if it works for you on Mac in Webstorm. Looking forward to hear from you soon. Thanks